# why are my Lucky Sevens outputs incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html

The outputs in the table for my Lucky Sevens game do not look right.  The 'Roll Count at Highest Amount Won' remains at 0 no matter how many time the game is run.  Can anybody see any glaring issues with my code?

The outputs in the table for my Lucky Sevens game do not look right.  The 'Roll Count at Highest Amount Won' remains at 0 no matter how many time the game is run.  Can anybody see any glaring issues with my code?

```js
function play() {
var startingBet = document.getElementById("betInput").value;
var money = startingBet;
var dice1;
var dice2;
var rollsAtMax = 0;
var rollsBeforeBroke = 0;
var maxWinnings = 0;



if(money <= 0){
alert("Starting bet needs to be greater than $0");

} else{

while (money > 0) {
rollsBeforeBroke++;
dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

if(dice1 + dice2 != 7) {
money = money - 1;
}else {
money = money + 4;

if(money > maxWinnings) {
maxWinnings = maxWinnings + money;
rollsBeforeBroke = rollsAtMax;
}
}

}
document.getElementById("results").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("money").innerText = '$ ' + startingBet;
document.getElementById("rollsBeforeBroke").innerText = rollsBeforeBroke;
document.getElementById("maxWinnings").innerText = '$ ' + maxWinnings;
document.getElementById("rollsAtMax").innerText = rollsAtMax;
}
return false;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Lucky Sevens</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="luckySevens.js"></script>
<link href="luckySevens.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>


<header>
<h1>Lucky Sevens</h1>
</header>

<label for="startingBet">Starting Bet:</label>
<input type="number" id="betInput" name="startingBet" value="$0.00">
<br />
<button onclick="play()">Play</button>


<hr />

<div id="results" style="display: none;">
<table><center>
<caption>Results</caption>
<tr>
<td>Starting Bet</td>
<td><span id="money"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total rolls before going broke</td>
<td><span id="rollsBeforeBroke"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Highest amount won</td>
<td><span id="maxWinnings"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Roll Count at Highest Amount Won</td>
<td><span id="rollsAtMax"></span></td>
</tr>
</center>
</table>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? SO is a _terrible_ debugger. Assert that the code you think is updating your properties is actually doing what you think. Also, you have duplicate info in your question. This is not how to solve the requirement that there be enough explanation to a snippet of code.  If you show your research you will be able to add plenty of words to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `rollsAtMax` variable is never changed in the code. So it will stay at 0

Comment: but rollsAtMax = rollsBeforeBroke which increments +1 (rollsBeforeBroke++) whenever the loop is run right??

Comment: rollsAtMax is put onto rollsBeforeBroke. I think you need to switch them around

Comment: Does this solve the whole question? If not please tell me what is missing. Otherwise mark this as answered